# Jenkins pipeline build in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to build multiple steps in Docker in Jenkins, but in console have this error:

```
jnlp-agent-pod-lwhwx seems to be running inside container 78f6224d8b5a34f5b709e354b1649abc4529f221a949725f8...
but /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline could not be found among []
but /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline@tmp could not be found among []
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline -v /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline:/home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline:rw,z -v /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline@tmp:/home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** node:14-alpine cat
$ docker top 4318a8d32d14fd27c706daa677ba9b663fd986d3b7923fee166f6 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build Back End)
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline@tmp/durable-36b64c56
```

The script file looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:14-alpine' }
    }
    stages {

        stage('Build Back End') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    git clone https://github.../mygit.git
                '''
            }
        }
}
```

does it mean my project is not in docker or how we can fix this?

Previously if we just used  `agent any`, there were no such errors, so probably something related to docker.

Comment: Are you doing docker in docker here; possibly also inside kubernetes?

Comment: yes, it is Jenkins on Kubernetes. i am quite new to this Jenkins stuff

Comment: Your workspace is probably failing to bind volume mount from a container inside a container. You should probably be using the kubernetes build agent, and not the docker build agent. This would also explain why `agent any` succeeded previously.

Comment: hmm, so we should have only agent any there? Will it work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was like you said, the docker is also implemented there, I just created a Dockerfile and built docker via `docker build` ... with leaving `agent: any`